# Recommendations on best papers / blogs / existing literature on constructing risk and vulnerability indices?

Tags: pca, references, dimensionality-reduction, risk, index-decomposition

I'm interested in constructing a risk index by indexing a large number of identified risk factors into a composite measure (that ideally then has sub-dimensions that can be explored further if one so chooses --- especially potentially linking these sub-dimensions in the form of cascading risks).

I'm wondering if you all have any suggestions on best practices or (ideally), have come across literature that identifies innovative approaches to this task (especially one that maybe integrates some qualitative information though this isn't a pre-requisite), or summarizes existing work / best practices on this topic.

A few examples just to give better context / get the conversation going ...

- https://www.anticipation-hub.org/news/multi-hazard-risk-analysis-methodologies#c2737
- https://mr-hn.github.io/pcaIndex/
- https://academic.oup.com/heapol/article/21/6/459/612115?login=false

Comment: See the classic by Keeney & Raiffa.  It's the *only* reference given in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-attribute_utility) on the subject!

Comment: Cheers -- will take a look!!